# Can you use app.all in the app.route stack in the express routing to save some lines of code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

can I use the app.all (.all) after the `app.route('/route')`?
Like this:

```
app.route('/route')
  .get((req, res) => console.log(req.method))
  .post((req, res) => console.log(req.method))
  .all((req, res) => console.log('all left methods'))
```

or I should use specific method on every http method? I have few like this to write and it will save me some lines if I can group all of the http methods which I do not want to allow to use but want to perform some error handling on them.
Otherwise maybe there is some specific error handling on methods not allowed?

Answer (score 0):

If you use app.all(), it will attach to all http methods.

> `app.all` attaches a particular piece of middleware to all HTTP methods,
>   and if attached in the main config file will globally apply the
>   middleware to all requests made to your app

You can use `app.all()` if you want that to be applied to all the http request coming from that route. Note that unlike, `app.use()`, the `app.all()` will only be applied to the http request that are coming from the exact specified route and not anything that follows it. Eg. `app.use('/something');` will apply to the router `/something/path` as well but that won't happen in case of `app.all()`

Usually, if you want to do something globally to all routes, app.use() is the better option. But, it depends on what you are using it for.

Comment: oh well, the code works as I wrote it, the all is executed only if there is not get or post request, so it works as I want it to  but I am just not sure if it is a correct way, your copy paste from Docs is pointless here

Comment: @MordimerMadderdin Well your question doesn't give much detail of what you are trying to do. I gave a concise detail on working of `app.all()`. You asked question about whether you should use specific method on every http method? That depends on your project. If your routes don't need separate attention for every type of http method request it gets, then you can use `app.all()`. Or you will have to use specific method on every method along with specific function you want to perform on that method request.

Comment: I just want to handle separately get and post and for every other method on this route I was to give a general error to the handler but with specific message, so I cant just skip them, looks like .all solve my problem in my tests, it indeed catches all the rest  methods which are not get and post. I did not catch any side effects for now that is why I  am asking if I can use it like this. Exactly like in my example in the  first post.